# Project Tuva and Linux

Tags: opensuse, moonlight

I'm interested in watching a few Project Tuva videos (http://research.microsoft.com/apps/tools/tuva/index.html). Right now, I'm running [openSUSE 11.2](http://software.opensuse.org/112/en). I've installed the Moonlight 3 preview from [go-mono.com](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/).

The site stopped saying that Silverlight3 is not supported on my browser. But then I've installed [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) and it quit complaining. But the loading data page appears to do nothing.

Is there an alternative way to access those videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking:

Project Tuva may require the [PlayReady DRM](http://www.microsoft.com/playready/default.mspx) which Moonlight does not support (and IMNSHO probably won't, ever, except for a few commercial versions on embedded devices.)

DRM on Linux typically refers to "direct rendering manager" for 3D support, not "digital [rights|restrictions] management" for content "protection".

Comment: How can I check if it requires PlayReady?

Comment: I am unsure, having never used Project Tuva. You may have luck asking them if they use the DRM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same message with Chrome (5.0.375.55) on Windows Vista.  In my situation, the browser could the be problem, but in your case, I'd suspect that Moonlight is the troublemaker.  I don't EXACTLY know all the capabilities of Moonlight, but I do know that it can't quite do all the same things as Silverlight (for instance, you can't watch Netflix movies with Moonlight).

Here are some questions:

- What browser are you using?
- What message do you get when you go here?
  http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx
  (On mine, it tells me that Silverlight is installed, but I still get the error message on the Tuva site)

Comment: I've tried both on Firefox and Chrome on Linux, get the same error. Moonlight works on a few samples I've tried. I don't get an error message after using User Agent Switcher - it just keeps saying Loading Data and do nothing at all.

Comment: What message do you get when you go to that link I posted?  It's the site that 'tests' whether or not you have Silverlight/Moonlight installed.  If it fails to recognize that Silverlight is installed, perhaps your browser isn't correctly utilizing it, or (as I suggested before) Moonlight can't do all the same things as Silverlight.